# $0 \in S_k$ for which k?

Tags: abstract-algebra, graded-rings

> If $S$ is a graded ring, for which $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ do we have $0 \in S_k$?

I think there shouldn't exist such a k. So as 0 is the empty sum we don't need this?

Comment: What is $S_k{}$?

Comment: $0$ belongs to each summand $S_k$. The ring is the direct sum $S=\bigoplus_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}S_k$ and these are subgroups of the additive group of $S$.

Comment: $0$ belongs to each $S_k$. This is why the "degree" of a homogeneous element $s$ of $S$ is not properly defined for every $s$, but you nevertheless can speak of "homogeneous elements of degree $k$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A $\mathbb{Z}$-graded ring $S$ is, as abelian group with respect to addition,
$$
S=\bigoplus_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}S_k
$$
where the $S_k$ are additive subgroups with the further property that
$$
S_hS_k\subseteq S_{h+k}
$$
as regards to multiplication.

Thus $0\in S_k$ for every $k$.